# Basics of electricity

Tags: current

   Lot of people generally travel on roads or highways. There may be chances that accidents or collisions may happen which would lead to the death of some people. Likewise the electrons when flowing in a wire, lot of collisions will occur and lot damage will happen to them. But why do the electrons don’t die while travelling in a wire?

Comment: If you collide with other people walking down a busy street, do you die? Of course not, you need more energy from a faster vehicle to do serious damage. To kill an electron, you need to accelerate it in a particle accelerator like the LHC. Even then it is not destroyed but reborn as something else, possibly pure energy. But this is off topic...

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes analogies help you understand things.  This is not one of those times.

Electrons do not take damage, at all.  They are fundamental particles in the Standard Model of quantum mechanics.  There are indeed collisions during the flow of current, but the way those collisions behave is completely and utterly unrelated to collisions on a highway.